# How to rename the class name in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to rename the class name in swift but it gives me error `Can't  refector swift code`. I want to know the best way to rename a file that will reflect in the whole project

Comment: global search & replace with cares

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839664/xcode-c-and-objective-c-refactoring

Comment: @moise2022: No, that question and its answers are for Objective-C and does not apply to Swift code.

Comment: Instead of renaming class, how about to use typealias?

Comment: @MartinR Xcode is the IDE in witch he's editing his code. Of yet, Xcode only refactor C and Objective-C code. The solution given in the above mentioned link is an alternative which applies to any other language you may write/edit in Xcode, Swift included.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode can only refactor C and Objective-C code. How to rename swift class name in Xcode 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133664/xcode-can-only-refactor-c-and-objective-c-code-how-to-rename-swift-class-name-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT, The Latest Solution**:

Starting Xcode 9 you can now do it easily. These are the steps:

1. Highlight the code that you want to rename
2. right click and choose `refactor` -> `rename`.

Or you can also use the `Editor` menu on top of the Xcode and choose `refactor` -> `rename`. Done!!

**Old solution for XCode 9 and below**:

1. click `Find` -> `Find and Replace in Workspace`

[image]

2. Rename it, for example I am renaming `ChatViewController` with `ChatVC` then hit `Enter`. This usually rename the naming in storyboard too, So it's really convinient, but just double check if you want to really make sure it's changed.

[image]

3. Lastly, Dont forget to rename the file itself in the project navigator

[image]

Answer (score 31):

Currently you can't refactor in Swift. However, you can do Find menu > Find and Replace in Project. (Carefully)

**Edit:** Xcode 9 allows you to refactor.

Highlight your property/function and choose Editor Menu -> Refactor -> Rename

Wait a second or two for Xcode 9 to scan your project for all occurrences and then type the new name.

Comment: You'd have to rename it in the project.pbxproj file as well, right?

Comment: @IvanLesko - no, if you rename it in all the source code that should be sufficient.

Comment: @Caroline wow, still after three years can't rename in Swift :/

Comment: @Caroline, nice! better late than never :) thanks for the heads up

Comment: In my case, I have to rename the file in Finder as well. Otherwise the class file cannot be found.

Comment: @Protocole - if you're renaming a file, you can do that in the Xcode Project Navigator. This will rename the file on disk. Additionally, as of Xcode 9, if you create a group, this will create a directory on disk, further organising the files on disk. (If you right click to create the group you can choose not to create a new directory.)

Answer (score 6):

Now it's possible in **Xcode 9**.

Right click on class name and choose **Rename**.

Answer (score 4):

After doing what @Caroline has pointed out, you should also change the name of your `.swift` file because it does not change using `Find > Find and replace...`. For doing that, you can click on the name of a `.swift` class and rename it as you want.

[image]

I am using `XCode 8` and it is the best option I could find to change the name of my class in the whole project.

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 9, to be released in fall 2017 - Developers would be able to - 
1. Refactor their Swift code.
2. Rename Swift project classes. 
3. Run multiple instances of the simulator at once.
4. Run and debug on physical devices wirelessly.
5. Access, pull, push and commit to Git directly from XCode.

My personal favorite is the way issues are highlighted in red in multiple lines completing the sentence of the issue.

[This WWDC 2017 session is a good view](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/102/)

XCode is getting smarter for us.

Comment: We can still use beta version available now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find & Replace by `cmd + shift + F`
2. Rename class name.
3. If you use storyboard/Nib file, don't forget change the class you assigned in `Show the identify inspector` to new class name.

**TIP** Set scope under the search field for `Find & Replace` can make this work clear.

Answer (score 0):

[AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) by Jetbrains can refactor/rename both Swift and Objective-C classes quite easily;
It's not free but it does a great job.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing similar error I was facing, where an error pops up when I choose the rename menu, just build the project and try again.
It seems like the Xcode needs some kind of parsing table to refactor the class name.